# Downloading files while changing url in a loop (pointers please)

Tags: database, loops, url

I'm trying to download a public database off the web that comes in multiple files.
http://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time
I'll have to repeat this across other databases so wouldn't mind figuring out how to implement this in a loop.

I know I can download with direct links e.g.
http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Download/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_1988_1.zip

and it's clear I'll have to write code to loop the year and quarter ####_#

I have no experience in this I'm at a loss as to where to begin or even what to search for - not even sure of a good program to work with urls. Any pointers on where to start would be great and I'll figure out the rest. All help deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Follow-up EDIT: 
Thank you Tonnie! Just want to share what I came up with so that others might benefit. Ran on windows via Cygwin.

```
----
#!/bin/bash -x
STARTYEAR=1988
ENDYEAR=2014


for year in $(seq $STARTYEAR $ENDYEAR)
do
        echo $year
        for q in $(seq 1 4)
        do
                wget
http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Download/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_"$year"_"$q".zip
        done
done
--------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wget is a program that works both on Windows and Linux. You can use it to download files from a website. All you need is a script that loops through the years and months.